# Energy calculation with implicit solvation

Tags: gaussian, solvation

I am trying to investigate a hydride transfer reaction of a transition-metal complex like the following:

$$
\ce{[M]-H + Ph3C+ -> [M]+ + Ph3CH}  
$$

For this I want to investigate the influence of solvation on the qualitative free Gibbs energies of the reaction. However, I am unsure about the proper procedure. These options come to mind:

- Single-Point calculation of the gas-phase structure with added solvation model + using the thermochemical corrections from the gas-phase
- Re-optimizing the gas-phase structure with added solvation model + new frequency calculation to obtain the thermochemical corrections

A look through literature did not really reveal a best-practice way on how to handle this. Would there be anything wrong with either procedure?

Comment: I would go by the second route, because solvent phase geometries are often different than gas phase. Not sure if there is any benchmark in literature over this.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial idea. Unfortunately, with SMD I do not get convergence for my transition-metal complexes. I've read multiple times that PCM might not be the best choice for charged species.

Comment: Which software are you using? Try solvent-accessible surface with SMD, it makes the PES smoother, and sometimes helps in convergence.

Comment: I'm using Gaussian16, I'll look into your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @SRMaiti I checked the Gaussian documentation, however, it states that the Solvent Accessible Surface option should only be used for Single Point calculations.

Comment: Then maybe try Solvent excluded surface? I am not sure abou Gaussian doc, because I had used Gaussian09 a long time ago, but I remember that geometry optimisations did run with SAS in Gaussian09, so not sure why it should be only used for single point

Comment: Did you try what SR Maiti suggest in the most recent comment? Have you figured this out yet? Please update us! Are you still actively seeking an answer?